# Facebook Toolkit 2.0 - Error when running it on a server with asp.net 2.0 installed

Tags: facebook, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the Facebook Connect toolkit on a server with ASP.Net 2.0 installed - I manually moved over System.Core and System.xml.Linq to the server from the 3.5 DLLs.

Most other things seem to run, until I try to access the "users" object - more specifically, the getinfo() method.

This is the error - anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Method not found: 'Void System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.set_MaxCharactersFromEntities(Int64)'.

[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.set_MaxCharactersFromEntities(Int64)'.]
   System.Xml.Linq.XNode.GetXmlReaderSettings(LoadOptions o) +0
   System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options) +60
   System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(String text) +7
   Microsoft.Xml.Schema.Linq.XTypedServices.Parse(String xml) +23
   facebook.users.getInfo(String uids) +201
   facebook.users.getInfo(Int64 uid) +34
   content_FBLoggedIn.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +481
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +15
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +34
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +47
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update - I actually ended up installing the 3.5 DLLs on the server - I couldn't find any other solution that worked out.

Once I did that, all problems went away.

Thanks for the tip though Ax - the server is running in 32 bits though.

Answer (score 1):

googleing for *set_MaxCharactersFromEntities* [suggests](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/3b770032-85be-45d7-8316-ee7cb120c174/#b6321089-410a-4e0b-9680-f3e89f9e2639) this might be a problem of 64 bit dlls on the server vs. 32bit dlls on the local development machine.